# What am I Doing Wrong Here... My for each loop is very slow

Tags: c#

I am trying to concatenate the strings in two files and save it in a third file. But when the records from the first two files are more (say 100000+ records) my output file takes a long time to generate. What am i doing wrong here... Can someone please help

```
 var fileA = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");
 var fileB = File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");
```

Then Do a cartesian of the Rows in the Files NxM where N and M represent the 
Number of rows in File1 and File2. So if there are 100 and 50 records each in 
File 1 and File2 Respectively, then the output is 100*50=5000

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("OutputFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
        // First, save the standard output.
        TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);


        foreach (var lst in cartesian)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lst);
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            Console.WriteLine(lst);
            Console.SetOut(tmp);
            Console.WriteLine(lst);
        }

        sw.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you tag all C# versions. You should only use `c#-x.x` if the question deals with `x.x` specifically (like a feature of that version, ...)

Comment: Perhaps its slow because a join like that across that many records is simply a *lot* of items to enumerate?

Comment: Furthermore your program reads 100k+ lines for the two files, that produces 10G+ lines in the resulting file... Since a processor can typically perform 1G instructions per second, I expect the program to take 100 seconds at least.

Comment: Sometimes code has a legitimate reason to be slow.  This looks like one of those times.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Agreed. I am looking for an alternative... Any suggestions?

Comment: You say your `for each` loop is "very slow". But you give us no idea how slow it actually is. (Ten seconds? Three days?) You don't say how long you expect it to take or how you came to that expectation. That makes it impossible for us to judge whether, for example, it's likely to be a hardware problem or whether your expectations are just unreasonable.

Comment: @Samuel: but the file is *inherently* large since you want to write 10G lines. You cannot write 10G lines without generating them first. It's not the algorithm itself that is "slow" it is the amount of data that is "huge".

Comment: @Samuel You need to change your requirement. Processing that much data is inherently slow; the only optimization I can see would be multi-threading (not that I'm actually suggesting you *do* that unless you are familiar with it already).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Here is are some info to help you... I am using a 32bit machine with 4GB RAM. To process a total of 100000 output records it takes 15minutes exactly. Havent tried it in a machine with higher configuration, yet feel that this is so slow to process/write just 100000 output rows.

Comment: @Samuel Even if that was true, you are doing a Cartesian cross; so its actually 10 *billion* rows of output, not 100,000 (and RAM is unlikely to be your chokepoint here)

Comment: If file A has 10 rows and file B has 10 rows, how many rows will the output file have? How many times will each entry in one of the files have to be processed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - If file A has 10 rows and file B has 10 rows, my output has 100 records and i need to iterate through these 100 records and write it into a file.

Comment: And how many rows do the two files that take 15 minutes have each? I'm trying to figure out how many output rows per second you are getting and how many output rows per second you are expecting.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I can give you the Answer directly. I am processing around 6600 lines per minute considering my system configuration i.e 32bit machine with 4GB RAM.

Comment: So your  input files are around 317 lines each?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Not necessarily to be equal lines in both the files. The above code does a cartesian product of the records in File A and File B. So it does nXm where n and m are records in File A and B.

Comment: Right. That's whyI asked him.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It just legitimately takes a long time to do a cartesian join of 100,000 x 100,000 records. You might improve performance a little bit by doing the join with nested `for` loops instead of LINQ, but your process is probably I/O bound.

Note that you don't need to use `Console.SetOut`, you can call `WriteLine` directly on `sw`:

```
foreach (var lst in cartesian)
{
  Console.WriteLine(lst);
  sw.WriteLine(lst);
  // and if you want to do it again: Console.WriteLine(lst);
}
```

Comment: @Samuel Note this shouldn't speed anything up much; just a piece of code you didn't need.

Comment: It might, depending on how much work `SetOut` does internally. If it flushes anything,for example.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine()` when writing to stdout is relatively heavy. See this test where I first just output 100000 lines to a text file with zero other processing, then the second test I write to stdout twice and call `SetOut` once each iteration. This is slightly different as your test writes to stdout twice but calls `SetOut` twice every iteration instead of only once.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\OutputFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
TextWriter tmp = Console.Out; // stdout since it hasn't been changed
Console.SetOut(sw); // point to file
var stopw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{               
    Console.WriteLine(i); // writes to file
}
sw.Dispose();
fs.Dispose();
var toFileTotalMs = stopw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

// Reset console to write to stdout
Console.SetOut(tmp);
stopw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i); // writes to stdout
    Console.SetOut(tmp); // point to stdout (every iteration)
    Console.WriteLine(i); // writes to stdout
}
var toConsoleTotalMs = stopw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine($"toFileTotalMs={toFileTotalMs}; toConsoleTotalMs={toConsoleTotalMs};");

Console.Read(); // leaves console window open
```

Outputs:

> toFileTotalMs    = 17.7198
>   toConsoleTotalMs = 15964.9133

So it takes 900 times longer to do two `Console.WriteLine()`'s to stdout and call `SetOut` than it does to just write to the file. I just tried changing the original for loop to call `SetOut` every iteration in addition to writing to file and it went from 17.7ms to 43.8ms.